# Values not being set properly in excel when trying to insert records from Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, pageobjects

I'm trying to store UserID, Password & EmailID which are being passed to the website that I'm trying to automate using selenium into an excel file. 
The problem is that the excel file that is being generated is storing UserID twice , the other two values are not being written to the excel.

[image]

What I want is to write userID, EmailID & Password next to each other.

My code is as follows:

```
 MfpCreateAccountPage createAccount =PageFactory.initElements(driver, MfpCreateAccountPage.class);

        createAccount.userDetails(randomAlphaNumericvalue, randomAlphaNumericvalue.toLowerCase()+ "@gmail.com" , randomAlphaNumericvalue);

        ExcelDriven.setCelldata(randomAlphaNumericvalue, 0, 0);
        ExcelDriven.setCelldata(randomAlphaNumericvalue.toLowerCase()+ "@gmail.com", 0, 1);
        ExcelDriven.setCelldata(randomAlphaNumericvalue, 0, 2);
```

Below is my code to write data into excel

public static String setCelldata(String text,int rownum,int col) throws IOException

```
{

        wb= new HSSFWorkbook();
        //sheet=wb.getSheet("script");
        sheet = wb.createSheet("Script");
        row=sheet.createRow(rownum);

        cell=row.createCell(rownum);
        cell.setCellValue(text);

        cell = row.createCell(col);
        cell.setCellValue(text);

        cell = row.createCell(col);
        cell.setCellValue(text);

        String celldata1= cell.getStringCellValue();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Data.xls"));
            wb.write(fos);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{

            if(fos!= null){
                    try{
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return celldata1;
    }
```

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: You seem to be passing the same variable `text` to `cell.setCellValue()` each time - should that be a different one?

Comment: The variable text contains 3 different values, i.e., userId, EmailID & password. Right now only userID & password are getting written into excel in the cells A1 & C1. I want all the 3 variables to be written into the excel. Thanks!!

Comment: You seem to be creating a brand new Workbook each time! Why aren't you creating it once, populating it, then saving at the end with all data added?

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it!